# How to Execute a command in target line of your Putty shortcut?

Tags: command-line, putty

For example, this is the target line:

```
C:\Putty_IPmsg\putty.exe -ssh  -pw "cmdctr123$$" cmdctr@10.226.151.84:22
```

It opens up a putty and auto logs in, with the username and password and IP address, and displays two options `1.DAT` and `2.APP`. How can I execute or select the "DAT" option using target command? so that when I click this target, it will auto login and auto select the "DAT" option.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not completely certain what you mean by "selecting an option", you could use `plink` to execute a command on a remote machine, which is from the authors of Putty and can be downloaded from the same site. `plink` can be used in a similar fashion to the `ssh` command (see chapter 7 of [official docs](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/index.html)), so you could just append the command you want to run on the other machine right after your current command:

```
plink.exe -ssh -pw "cmdctr123$$" cmdctr@10.226.151.84 -P 22 COMMAND
```

Unfortunately I could not test this particular command line myself.

Note that specifying a password on a command line is **potentially unsafe** ([discussion of linux users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607675/shell-script-password-security-of-command-line-parameters)). I recommend using private/public key authentication with `pageant`, as stated in the docs of `plink` ([official docs](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/index.html)):

> To avoid being prompted for a password, you should almost certainly
>   set up public-key authentication. (See chapter 8 for a general
>   introduction to public-key authentication.) Again, you can do this in
>   two ways:
>
> - Set up a PuTTY saved session that describes the server you are
>     connecting to, and that also specifies a private key file (see 
>     section 4.18.5). For this to work without prompting, your private key will need to 
>     have no passphrase.
> - Store the private key in Pageant. See chapter 9 for further information.